# Add values to a combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, playframework

I have an xtype combo that I have created and want to add a Yes and No option for the user to select. This is the code that I have so far:

```
{
                        xtype:'combo',
                        fieldLabel: 'Option List',
                        id: 'option',
                        width: 40
                    }
```

Is there an easy way to add the values within the combo or am I going to have to create a whole cbTemplate with a Ext.data.store?

Comment: if you just looked at the docs on combobox you would know the answer immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create the store inside the combobox:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Option List',
    store:  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['name', 'id'],
        data : [
            {"name":"Yes", "id":"yes"},
            {"name":"No", "id":"no"}
        ]
    }),
    editable: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/arunv/TrRHP/

Answer (score 1):

Seriously the simplest possible config to add a yes / no combo is:

```
{
   xtype: 'combo',
   store: ['yes', 'no']
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/gBpW6/